# Search backward for first line not matching a pattern?

Tags: search

Is there a way search backward from the cursor for a line that doesn't contain a pattern?

For example, many of my lines match the regular expression `^   adding: \i\+`.  I want to find the first line above the current line which doesn't match this pattern, even if it is an empty line.

I don't want to use zero-width matching expressions because I don't want to have to specify a non-zero-width matching portion, which could cause the search to miss some qualifying lines.

I also avoided global commands, including the inverse global command `:v`, because I want to search backward from the cursor to the first occurrence.

Comment: I initially thought to try `:help pattern`; maybe there's a negate-a-pattern syntax? `\@!` and `\@<!` looked promising, but I couldn't make them work (i.e., it's not as simple as `\(pattern\)\@<!.`). Only other thing to add is that `?pattern?-1` takes you to the line above a pattern match, so with `hlsearch` turned on you could just hold `n` until you're on an un-highlighted line. Or you could write a while loop to search backwards...

Comment: I tried paging backward until I saw unhighlighted text, but it's such high volume that detection is unreliable.  Other workarounds is to use global with inverse matching to prepend a unique string to nonmatching lines, then search backword for the string.  I prefer not to mess with file, and not to assume uniqueness of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case, you can use a zero-width negative match and still have it work on empty lines.

> I don't want to use zero-width matching expressions because I don't want to have to specify a non-zero-width matching portion, which could cause the search to miss some qualifying lines.

So you can use the `^` as the matching portion outside the zero-width negative lookahead.

This works:

```
?^\( adding: \i\+\)\@!
```

It will properly skip the `adding:` lines and it will stop on all other lines, including empty ones.

Comment: Thanks, filbranden. I ran into problems in the past assuming that positional anchors like `^` counted as matches, but I don't recall the environment (most likely Matlab).  Thankfully, not vim.

Comment: Damn. I fiddled for ages and couldn’t make this work. Nice job.